# SQL Project in VSTS Continuous Integration via WinRM

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, continuous-integration, dacpac

Here is my solution.
I have a DB project in it, which multiple publish profiles. When I run publish from Visual Studio Manually by loading any profile it works perfectly.

[image]

We have our IIS in Azure VM and SQL in another Azure VM

We have a Continuous builds setup on Visual Studio Team Services, which will deploy site to Azure VM.

To the same build definition, I added a **WinRm - SQL Server DB Deployment**
Here is my Buil defination for dacpac step

[image]
[image]

When I run my build I get the following error

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment on one
>   or more machines failed. System.Exception: Invalid Publish Profile [
>   xxxxxxx ] provided

I don't really find any references on how to give profile information and why is it failing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

---

In order to resolve this as per @Jason Ye - MSFT suggestion, I copied my publish profile to Azure SQL VM and copied its full path and updated the profile path in build definition.

Then I got stuck with the following issue

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment on one
>   or more machines failed. System.Exception: Publishing to database
>   'DbName' on server 'xxxxxx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com'. *** Could
>   not load package from '**/*.dacpac'. Illegal characters in path.

Since dacpac will keep changing, I cannot copy it to server before. How to get the path.

Comment: Publish profile provide fine-grained control over SQL Server database creation or upgrades. Specify the path to the Publish profile XML file on the target machine or on a UNC share that is accessible by the machine administrator's credentials. This is an optional parameter. However, if the seletced option for the 'Specify SQL Using' parameter is Publish Profile XML file, then this is a required parameter. please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup).

Comment: So it should be like full path of target machine, like c:/ users/username/site/Mysore/dbproject/profile.publish.xml ?

Comment: Please try it :)

Comment: How can I give that Path. as I will not have my SQL PROJECT deployed in target machine right. It is still on VSTS source Code. it is being executed from VSTS and i will not have full path for that